# Zurb Foundation 5 grid - Control no of columns at small - med - large

Tags: zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 5

I am trying to to get my large 6 column layout to go to medium 3 columns and then to small 2 columns as in the following images.  Is this possible using the Foundation grid

Large 6 columns

[image: large 6 column]

Small 2 Coumns

[image: small 2 columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya it is possible using Foundation 5. All you have to do is use respective classes

```
<div class="large-6 medium-3 small-2 columns">
..    
..
</div>
```